# Amazon S3 GUI client for OS X

Tags: macos, gui, amazon-s3

I'm looking for a good GUI client for Amazon S3. On Windows I used Cloudberry Explorer and I would like to know if there's anything like that for Mac OS X.

Comment: Which ones have you already found and why didn't they work for you?

Comment: I'm very new to Mac so I haven't really tried anything yet. Thought it would be a good idea to see if anyone could recommend a good s3 client first.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are **not for recommendations** (see [FAQ]). It takes only a couple of minutes to probably find three or more S3 clients for OS X, which you should evaluate yourself, based on what *you personally* need. If you have a specific problem with any of those clients, feel free to ask a question about it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) works with S3 among others.

Comment: I also tried Dragondisk, it seems to be a very good program.

Comment: [CrossFTP](http://www.crossftp.com) is a good GUI client for Amazon S3 and CloudFront management.

Comment: I either use [3Hub](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/3hub/id427515976) or aws-cli